# How to use wvdial instead of network-manager in Debian

Tags: linux-networking

I would like to get rid of network-manager as it seems to be too magic for me.

However for the life of me I cannot figure out how to connect my UMTS-stick using wvdial (network-manager has no problems with it).

Here the network-manager config:

```
[connection]
id=O2 connection
uuid=c7759b65-8115-4019-bb99-72dd82037f5a
type=gsm
autoconnect=false

[gsm]
number=*99#
apn=surfo2

[ppp]
lcp-echo-failure=5
lcp-echo-interval=30

[serial]  
baud=115200

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

I have tried this configuration for wvdial:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init5 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","surfo2"
Init7= AT+COPS?
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Baud = 115200
New PPPD = yes
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
ISDN = off
Username = whatever
Password = whatever
Ask Password = 0
Dial Command = ATD
Stupid Mode = 1
Auto DNS = no
Idle Seconds = 5000
Carrier Check = No
Phone=*99#
```

However I only get a "NO CARRIER"-error.

I have deliberately inserted a AT+COPS? and before the no-carrier I can see this output:

```
 --> Sending: AT+COPS?
 AT+COPS?
 +COPS: 0,0,"O2 (Germany) GmbH & Co. OHG",2
 OK
```

So it seems the modem connects to my provider but for whatever reason fails to detect a carrier.

How can I attack this?

Many thanks!

PS: I am using Debian testing